# How should I index this MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I've got a table with the following columns:

```
(imageID, albumID, accountID, imageLoc, albumLoc, and uploadDate)
```

Where

- `imageID` is a unique identifier for each image,
- `albumID` is the identifier for which album the image belongs to,
- `accountID` is the id of the account the image belongs to,
- `imageLoc` is the location of the image on the server,
- `albumLoc` is the location of the image within an album (ex. 3rd image of album) and
- `uploadDate` is the date the image was uploaded.

I'm guessing I'll index `imageID` because that's what's going to be referred to most but I"m also going to be using the `albumID` to find all images in the album, so should I index that too?

Thank you!

Comment: I would only index the unique identifier imageID...at least, this is how I structure all of my tables

Comment: Is `imageID` the primary key? Please show us some queries and the full schema for a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Dont index unless you need to. Indexes slow down inserts and updates. So by adding indexes that are not used in `SELECT` or reading of data you are just adding no value.

Enable the slow query log to find queries that take a while to run. Using these identified queries run the `EXPLAIN` statement with the queries and analyse the output.

You are doing optimization by guessing which is not going to work. The output of explain will show you when a slow query is not using a index. Once you have identified these indexes add them.

A index that is never used add more space and more operations to a database which just makes it slower.

Answer (score 0):

Although I partially agree with Namphibian, I disagree about dont index unless you need to.  The index on the primary ID for join purposes is obviously one you would need.  However, if your queries as you are projecting will also be regularly using your album ID, then I WOULD preemptively have an index on (primary ID, album ID) so it would cover both joins AND query criteria.   Or, depending on situation, might be better by (album id, primary id).. again, based on how query conditions are purposed.

Comment: I agree with you but since I had no real table structure to work with I rather not guess. NOt having indexes on primary and foreign keys are so basic it did not even enter my mind.